# How to add a callback in an event handler in a legacy MFC code?

Tags: c++, multithreading, callback, mfc

This is a toy implementation of a legacy code using MFC. `OnBnClickedButton` is an event handler but it contains codes which are executed asynchronously in a different thread ( may be a bad idea). The declaration syntax is accepted by the message map.

```
//declaration
afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton(); 
//message map
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON, &CMFCApplicationDlg::OnBnClickedButton)
```

Now I want to add a callback to the event handler like so, but the message-map  won't accept the new declaration syntax, where to go?

```
afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton(std::optional<std::function<CString(void)>> callback);
```

Comment: You can't add new parameters to an established event. [MFC button handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/user-button-handlers?view=msvc-170) don't accept any parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function signatures and return values for entries in MFC [message maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-maps-mfc) are fixed. You have to follow the protocol; it doesn't offer any customization points. In case of the `ON_BN_CLICKED` [button handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/user-button-handlers) the prototype must abide to the following signature

```cpp
afx_msg void memberFxn();
```

It doesn't accept or return any values. The only state available is that implied from the message map entry (i.e. `OnBnClickedButton` is called whenever the child control of the dialog represented by `CMFCApplicationDlg` with ID `IDC_BUTTON` is clicked).

In your implementation of `OnBnClickedButton` you are free to do whatever you like, such as querying for additional information (e.g. from data stored in the class instance or thread-local storage), spinning up threads, either explicitly or using C++20 coroutines, etc.

MFC doesn't help you with any of that, specifically it doesn't provide any sort of support for asynchronous operations. That's something you will have to implement yourself.